# Segfault Error in Sinatra After Upgrading to Ruby 2.0 Beta

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, sinatra, upgrade, ruby-2.0

I'm reporting this because I haven't found any other reports of code that worked previously, but now generates random Ruby segmentation fault errors after upgrading to the just-released `Ruby 2.0.0-p0`.

I have a Sinatra application that generates a string that an `.erb` template embeds in a `data-` tag in the DOM. As I stated, this worked just fine until I upgraded to Ruby 2.0. With `2.0.0-p0`, It gives segmentation fault errors, usually after about 5 to 20 runs of the program. When I revert to Ruby 1.9, it works perfectly again and I can run the program hundreds of times without problems.

Here's an example of the results I get from these errors. This is the first few lines of the 'control frame information' section of the error listing:

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0061 p:0028 s:0315 e:000303 METHOD terrain_001.rb:509
c:0060 p:0012 s:0298 e:000296 BLOCK  terrain_001.rb:494 [FINISH]
c:0059 p:---- s:0294 e:000293 CFUNC  :each
c:0058 p:0008 s:0291 e:000290 BLOCK  terrain_001.rb:493 [FINISH]
c:0057 p:---- s:0288 e:000287 CFUNC  :each
c:0056 p:0023 s:0285 e:000284 METHOD terrain_001.rb:492
c:0055 p:0068 s:0281 e:000279 BLOCK  /home/john/Desktop/stra-dams/views/index.erb:3 [FINISH]
```

The line numbers indicated as the location where the error occured are always in the following code, somewhere inside the definition for the hash `values{}` after the `encode` method has been called by the line `str << encode(hex)` in the `terrain_string` method:

```
def terrain_string
  str = ""
  @terrain = build_terrain
  @terrain.each do |t|
    t.each do |hex|
      str << encode(hex)
    end
  end
  str
end


# encode elevation values to a one-character code
def encode(elev)
  values = {
    :elev_10 => "a",
    :elev_20 => "b",
    :elev_30 => "c",
    :elev_40 => "d",
    :elev_50 => "e",
    :elev_60 => "f",
    :elev_70 => "g",
    :elev_80 => "h",
```

Maybe after other people have tried the brand new Ruby 2.0 release, others will report similar errors. In the meantime, is there anything else I should be looking at that might help pinpoint the problem with the `2.0.0-p0` release?

Comment: I'd run it without Sinatra and see if the same error occurs, maybe in a loop in IRB. I think you'd be better off [submitting a bug report](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/). The core team seem nice to me, I wouldn't worry if it's found to be your error, a segmentation fault is hardly likely to be down to you, and I'd expect it from a .0 release. Of course, if the problem goes away when not using Sinatra, hit their [issue tracker](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues?direction=desc&milestone=10&sort=created&state=open) first!

Comment: Thanks, Iain. After posting this, I ran the ruby file as a standalone without Sinatra and it worked just fine.

Comment: Ok, glad you're getting closer! It'd be best to open an issue with Sinatra then, in case there's something in code that isn't working correctly with Ruby 2.

Answer (score 2):

I get something very similar using a my new open-source framework on Ruby 2.0.0. There seems to be something wrong with Ruby 2.0.0-p0 causing these segfaults, or otherwise some compatibility issue with a common gem. It's random nature makes it very difficult to work out what library is responsible, if any.

I seem to get the error the most when my web app is run in a multi-threaded or forked mode, such as with Phusion Passenger's smart spawning method. I'm just banking on the fact that it'll be fixed in the next patch level for ruby 2.0.0.

Note, the actually segfaults occurs at verious points in the execution. Sometimes within Nokogiri, sometimes in ERB, SASS or Tilt. Basically, it's a timing issue. My app is tiny, and so spends the most time rendering templates and post-processing the response in Nokogiri, so that's where the segfaults occur most of the time.